# extract data from pipe delimited String

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi i have a table where the data is stored in string format which is pipe delimited , now i need to extract data  from string and create columns. sample of the data which is stored as string is :

```
"<U|'3526'|2|1|EMAIL_ID|kaye.warne@gradusworld.com, melanie.farnan@corptraveller.co.uk>"
```

now i need to fetch data like below :

[image: U '3526' 2 1 EMAIL_ID kaye.warne@gradusworld.com, melanie.farnan@corptraveller.co.uk]

Can any one help me with this please. Thanks

Comment: Use a [string splitting function](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings), and then pivot.

Comment: is the number of columns fixed? (6 columns in example u shared)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, there are many articles on this, we are not here to simply do your work for you.

Comment: Hi yes the number is fixed, i have i got the result=, i tried a combination of substring and patindex to extract data

Answer (score 4):

There are whole lot many articles out there explaining how to perform string splits, recommend to read them one for example is [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

One way to achieve what you ask is below -

```
DECLARE @S varchar(max),
        @Split char(1),
        @X xml
SELECT @S = '<U|''3526''|2|1|EMAIL_ID|kaye.warne@gradusworld.com, melanie.farnan@corptraveller.co.uk>',
       @Split = '|'
SELECT @S = REPLACE(REPLACE(@S,'<',''),'>','')
SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,' <root> <myvalue>' + REPLACE(@S,@Split,'</myvalue> <myvalue>') + '</myvalue>   </root> ')

SELECT DISTINCT 
  T.c.value('(/root/myvalue)[1]','VARCHAR(20)')  ,
  T.c.value('(/root/myvalue)[2]','VARCHAR(20)'),
  T.c.value('(/root/myvalue)[3]','VARCHAR(20)'),
  T.c.value('(/root/myvalue)[4]','VARCHAR(20)'),
  T.c.value('(/root/myvalue)[5]','VARCHAR(20)'),
  T.c.value('(/root/myvalue)[6]','VARCHAR(2000)')
 FROM @X.nodes('/root/myvalue') T(c)
```